# Dynamically change the class name Vue

Tags: vue.js

```
 <div
        v-bind:class="[updateClassValue? 'chat-item me' :  'chat-item stranger']" 
        v-for="message in msg"
        :key="message.messageId"
      >
```

```
  updateClassValue() {
   for ( const eachMsg in this.msg.itemList) {

      if (eachMsg._sender.userId !== this.nickname) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
      }
   }
  }
```

I want the div to have class name 'chat-item me' when updateClassValue is true and 'chat-item stranger' otherwise. Yet, somehow above code only results in 'chat-item stranger'. If anyone could give me some insight, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `updateClassValue` is a method or computed property?

Comment: It is a method!

Comment: Can you also share what data `msg` holds?

Comment: Instead of `updateClassValue?` write `updateClassValue() ?` to call the method. You are currently only checking if the method exists. A computed property, like in the answer below, doesn't have to do that.

Comment: Can you please confirm `this.msg` is an array or object ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, You have a set of messages in a chat window and you want to add styles to make differentiate between messages you sent and the messages you received from other person. If Yes, you can directly do that in template itself without any separate method/computed property.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    msg: {
        itemList: [{
        messageId: 1,
        userId: 1,
        text: 'Hi'
      }, {
        messageId: 2,
        userId: 2,
        text: 'Hello'
      }, {
        messageId: 3,
        userId: 1,
        text: 'How are you ?'
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.chat-item-me {
  background-color: green;
}

.chat-item-stranger {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div
        v-for="message in msg.itemList"
        :key="message.messageId"
        v-bind:class="message.userId === 1 ? 'chat-item-me' :  'chat-item-stranger'" 
      >
      {{ message.text }}
  </div>
</div>
```